# how to add animation in multiple months datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a simple datepicker and I would like to give him a slide effect when I press the next/previous icon.

You can see an example here (click the date): http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

JqueryUI has a datepicker widget that might just do exactly what you want.  It is super easy to set up too.  Documentation at http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/Hxbew/

Just the datepicker might not give the exact feature you want out of the box. You might need to adjust the

- [showAnim](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showAnim) with [showOptions](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOptions)
- [showOtherMonths](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOtherMonths)

to get the required feature.

Hope this helps